# ¿Como puedo hacer que el contenido del sidebar este hacia la derecha del mismo?

Tags: css, reactjs, css3, selectores-css

Estoy intentando hacer un sidebar (un navbar pero de costado, mas precisamente lado izquierdo), que muestre el contenido de las pestañas a la derecha del mismo, ahora mismo todo el contenido de todas las pestañas se muestran abajo del navbar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la imagen hay un pequeño texto que dice 'nueva venta', este contenido deberia estar a la derecha del sidebar, pero por alguna razon no puedo hacer que se ponga a la derecha, lo mismo sucede con todas las otras pestañas.

El navbar:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import "./NavBar.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export const NavBar = () => {
  const [isOpenCompras, setIsOpenCompras] = useState(false);
  const [isOpenContactos, setIsOpenContactos] = useState(false);
  const [isOpenFacturas, setIsOpenFacturas] = useState(false);
  const [isOpenReportes, setIsOpenReportes] = useState(false);
  const [isOpenConfiguracion, setIsOpenConfiguracion] = useState(false);
  const [isOpenAdministrarAcceso, setIsOpenAdministrarAcceso] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h1>Usuario</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to={"/"}>Inicio</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li onClick={() => setIsOpenCompras(!isOpenCompras)}>
              <NavLink to={"/Compras"}>Compras</NavLink>
            </li>
            {isOpenCompras && (
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/NuevaCompra"}>Nueva Compra</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/HistorialDeCompra"}>
                    {" "}
                    Historial De Compra{" "}
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            )}
            <li onClick={() => setIsOpenContactos(!isOpenContactos)}>
              <NavLink to={"/Contactos"}>Contactos</NavLink>
            </li>
            {isOpenContactos && (
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/Clientes"}>Clientes</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/Proveedor"}>Proveedor</NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            )}
            <li onClick={() => setIsOpenFacturas(!isOpenFacturas)}>
              <NavLink to={"/Facturacion"}>Facturacion</NavLink>
            </li>
            {isOpenFacturas && (
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/NuevaVenta"}>Nueva Venta</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/AdministrarFactura"}>
                    Administrar Factura
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            )}
            <li onClick={() => setIsOpenReportes(!isOpenReportes)}>
              <NavLink to={"/Reportes"}>Reportes</NavLink>
            </li>
            {isOpenReportes && (
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/ReporteDeCompras"}>Reporte de Compras</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/ReporteDeVentas"}>Reporte de Ventas</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/ReporteDeInventarios"}>
                    Reporte de Inventarios
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/ReporteDeUtilidades"}>
                    Reporte de Utilidades
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            )}
            <li onClick={() => setIsOpenConfiguracion(!isOpenConfiguracion)}>
              <NavLink to={"/Configuracion"}>Configuracion</NavLink>
            </li>
            {isOpenConfiguracion && (
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/PerfilDeLaEmpresa"}>
                    Perfil de la empresa
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/Monedas"}>Monedas</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/Impuestos"}>Impuestos</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/Plantillas"}>Plantillas</NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            )}
            <li
              onClick={() =>
                setIsOpenAdministrarAcceso(!isOpenAdministrarAcceso)
              }
            >
              <NavLink to={"/AdministrarAcceso"}>Administrar Acceso</NavLink>
            </li>
            {isOpenAdministrarAcceso && (
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/GrupoDeUsuarios"}>Grupo de usuarios</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/Usuarios"}>Usuarios</NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            )}
            <li>
              <NavLink to={"/Fabricante"}>Fabricante</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to={"/Producto"}>Producto</NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </>
  );
};
```

El side var tiene estados que les permite ocultar pestañas o mostrarlas al momento de hacer clikcs, nada de otro mundo.

este seria el css:

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #4169FF;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 14rem;
}

ul li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Como ven el css es sencillo, pero desde mi experiencia el contenido de las pestañas deberian ocupar el lado derecho, ya que designe un **width de 14rem**.

Nota de color: Algo que me funciono a media es poner la propiedad **position: fixed** en el header, junto un left y bottom de '0' (cero) esto lo que hacia era poner el contenido de la pestaña detras del navbar (ocultando par del contenido que la pestaña alberga) si bien con pequeñas modificaciones podia lograr que viera todo el contenido seria impractico, ya que tengo muchas pestañas y como dije arriva, el contenido deberia aparecer de manera natural a la derecha.

**¿Como puedo hacer que el contenido de las pestañas aparezcan a la derecha y no abajo?**

Comment: Puedes revisar esta alternativa utilizando Bootstrap : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/  trae una serie de ejemplos quizás alguno se ajuste a tus necesidades.